# How to process a line of input from right to left?

Tags: input, right-to-left

If I have a line of command like: -r -p -s
And '-r', '-p', '-s' has its own function, and I cannot use split. then how can I take the input from right to left

Comment: "I cannot use split" smacks of an artificial limitation. Can I ask *why* you cannot use `split`? Also you haven't specified a language, which is important.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.